# Calculate percentage variation of values of current year and previous year for the same period in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in my database that contains values corresponding to each date. I need to calculate the percentage variation in count of values of  current year and previous year for the same period. By period I mean from January first to current date in the year.  How to do this in SQL. I am using SQL Server. My table structure is like this.

```
Id          |  Date   
-------------------------  
1xxxxx      |  01-01-2014  
2xxxxx      |  14-01-2014  
3xxxxx      |  01-03-2014  
4xxxxx      |  12-10-2014  
5xxxxx      |  01-12-2014  
6xxxxx      |  02-03-2015  
7xxxxx      |  04-03-2015  
8xxxxx      |  11-04-2015
```

Comment: Please show us the **table structures** (columns, datatypes), some **sample data** and your expected results .....

Comment: Which dbms? (date/time is too often product specific functionality...)

Comment: Your question is still not very clear. if you provide a sample of input and the desired output you will improve your chance of getting the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare 
  @today date,
  @prev_year_today date,
  @this_year_count int,
  @prev_year_count int,
  @percentage_change float

set @today = getdate()
set @prev_year_today = dateadd(year, -1, @today)

select 
  @this_year_count = count(*) 
from 
  some_values
 where
  year <= @today and
  datepart(year, year) = datepart(year, @today)

select
  @prev_year_count = count(*)
from
  some_values
where
  year <= @prev_year_today and
  datepart(year, year) = datepart(year, @prev_year_today)

 set @percentage_change = 100.00 * (@this_year_count - @prev_year_count) / @prev_year_count
 select @percentage_change
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a2b3/2)